# Work around for MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit TimePicker SelectedTimeChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I am using TimePicker from [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/). But it does not have a 
`SelectedTimeChanged` event similar to WPF stock DatePicker's `SelectedDateChanged`event.

Currently I am binding the TimePicker's Text to get something similar. But the problem is that the Text gets updated a couple of times before user finishes picking the time.

Is anyone familiar with the toolkit and knows any work arounds?

XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Class="DateTimePickerTest.CustomDateTimePicker"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DateTimePickerTest"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <Grid>

        <materialDesign:TimePicker Name="timePicker" Width="100" Height="30"
                                       Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDateTimePicker}},
                                        Path=Time}">
        </materialDesign:TimePicker>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DateTimePickerTest
{
    public partial class CustomDateTimePicker : UserControl
    {
        private string _Time;
        public string Time
        {
            get { return _Time; }
            set
            {
                _Time = value;
                TimePicked();
            }
        }

        public CustomDateTimePicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void TimePicked()
        {
            if (timePicker.SelectedTime != null)
            {
                _Time = timePicker.SelectedTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt");
                MessageBox.Show(_Time);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `SelectedTime` property instead of `Text` property and set `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`.

Comment: @dhilmathy That works.. Thank you.. If you could post this as an answer I will mark it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `SelectedTime` property instead of `Text` property of `TimePicker` control. Also set `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`. Like,

```
<mDesign:TimePicker Name="timePicker" Width="100" Height="30"
                    SelectedTime="{Binding Time, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                 AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDateTimePicker}, 
                                   UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
</mDesign:TimePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the `SelectedTime` property of the control to a `DateTime?` source property:

```
public partial class CustomDateTimePicker : UserControl
{
    private DateTime? _Time;
    public DateTime? Time
    {
        get { return _Time; }
        set
        {
            _Time = value;
            TimePicked();
        }
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void TimePicked()
    {
        if (_Time.HasValue)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_Time.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<materialDesign:TimePicker Name="timePicker" Width="100" Height="30"
                           SelectedTime="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDateTimePicker}}, Path=Time}">
</materialDesign:TimePicker>
```

The source property will then be set when you select a time in the view.

Comment: In an ideal scenario this should work. But I guess there is a bug in the toolkit's Timepicker. Similar to the Text property, SelectedTime too gets set a couple of times before the user finishes picking a time.Thanks for the answer.